# Add tabs at the beginning of every line in console.log for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use console.log a lot in my code for better debugging. For example, in my `cart.js` file in the `controllers` folder, inside `getProductsInCart` function, I do:

**controllers/cart.js**

```js
console.log('[controllers/cart.js].getProductsInCart', '\nproducts =', products);`
```

which gives me the following result in the **terminal**:

```js
[controllers/cart.js].getProductsInCart // <-- where `products` object is located 
products = [
  {
    productId: new ObjectId("645a54116710e60e28b96903"),
    quantity: 1,
    _id: new ObjectId("645a6e2e119c195fd8b32f99")
  }
]
```

My `products` object is fetched from MongoDB. However, when I start having more and more functions and variables in different files, the log would be a bit hard to read.

Therefore, I expect every variable being logged in the terminal to look as follows:

```json
[controllers/cart.js].getProductsInCart
        products = [
            {
                productId: new ObjectId("645a54116710e60e28b96903"),
                quantity: 1,
                _id: new ObjectId("645a6e2e119c195fd8b32f99")
            }
        ]
```

How can I add 2 tabs at the beginning of every line for my `products` value to look like that?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224130/formatting-text-with-tabs-or-spaces) old post it may answer to your question.

Comment: I recommend using a better logger, e.g. [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston).

Comment: @jabaa thank you for your suggestion but I need to keep things simple when debugging for specifically logical errors, where there is no error thrown yet the behavior of the program is not as expected because of missing/incorrect values

Comment: With a normal logger you can set log levels for error, warning, info and debug. You can configure the output format, e.g. JSON, XML, plain text with tabs. You can write debug logs to console and error logs into a file or to a network socket. Winston is a really simple logger. Every serious project I've worked on had a logger like this. If you're working on a sandbox project, just to play around, you should mention it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're against bringing a logging library into your project, consider using `JSON.stringify()` to add extra indentation to the products object or `console.group()`/`console.groupEnd()` to add indentation to all lines printed in between, or the combination of both.

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#syntax)'s third parameter adds a number of spaces to each level of the object nesting in the resulting string:

```
console.log('something', 'products =', JSON.stringify(products, null, 5))
```

The caveat is that the number of spaces multiplies with each level of nesting.

[console.group() / groupEnd()](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consolegrouplabel) let you indent the lines between them:

```
console.group();
console.log('1'); // indented
console.groupEnd();
console.log('2'); // not indented
```

[console.dir()](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoledirobj-options) is another useful tool for logging objects. It adds colors to property values, which usually helps readability.